# How can I save the outputs of every iteration into structure

Tags: matlab

I have a question please.
I write a script that it's outputs are `B`, a number and `C`, a matrix with size `3,3,3`.

I must run this script with random inputs in 100 iterations. and the outputs of every iteration are `B` and `C`. I want to save these outputs at the end of each iteration in structure named for example ST.

How can do it please? How can create this empty structure that fill with B and C at the end of each iteration?

Thank you.

My code:

```
a1=[1 0 1;0 1 1;0 0 0];
b1=[0 1 0;1 0 0;0 0 1];
c1=[0 0 0;0 0 0;1 1 0];
D=cat(3,a1,b1,c1);
A=zeros(3,3);
for i=1:3
for j=1:3
p1=0
p=0
idx=randperm(numel(A))
[m n]=ind2sub(size(A),idx(find((A(idx)==0),1,'first')))
s=find(D(m,n,:)==1)
for i=1:3
for j=1:3
for k=s
if D(i,j,k)~=1
p(i,j,k)=suit(i,j,k).^2
elseif D(i,j,k)==1
p(i,j,k)=0 
end
end
end
end
w=sum(sum(sum(p)))
p1=p./w
p2=p1(:,:,k)
r=rand
c=reshape(p2,1,[])
c=cumsum(c)
j=find(r<=c,1,'first')
[j1 j2]=ind2sub(size(p2),j)
g=find(D(j1,j2,:)==1)
D(j1,j2,g)=0
D(m,n,g)=1
D(m,n,s)=0
D(j1,j2,s)=1
x=D
end
```

I want to iterate this code.

Comment: I add the code to my question. I want to iterate this code. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
% Define an empty structure
ST = struct('B', {}, 'C', {});

for i = 1:100

       % Do your computation here
       % Define the variables B and C 

       ST(i).B = B;   % Store B and C in the ith element of the structure
       ST(i).C = C;
end
```

Hope this helps.